# Given two dependent sequences, predict next output for one of them

Tags: time-series, classification

I have a problem which can be generalized as follows. There is some black-box which produces actions {0, 1}. Having two sequences: ***X*** - series of previous actions, ***T*** - series of time intervals between actions, how can I predict next action? ***T*** in this problem is just additional data, I am not interested in predicting time of next action.

Which methods can be used for this problem? My only idea right now is HMM, but maybe there are other options?

**UPDATE:**

After a mini investigation via google.com I've found that best results in problem of binary sequence prediction currently is obtained by evolving state transition rules of finite automata (see [this paper](http://www.dm.unito.it/~cerruti/doc-html/pubb/prediction.pdf)). This method allows up to 70% accurate prediction of standard random generator algorithm used in most programming languages.

So the question now is how to modify initial method in order to use additional information from ***T*** sequence in my question. The only way I can think of right now is: discretize T and build one more finite state machine which works on ***T*** sequence, then combine both FSMs into one system and try to evolve best set of transition rules for it. But, this idea looks too complicated, and unclear in details right now. There should be something simpler to try first.

Comment: I don't understand what T does if X already gives you the sequence of observations...

Comment: T does exactly what was stated in the initial question: gives additional information about how much time passed before state in X was changed. All question is actually about, how to utilize this additional information in order to better predict X.